# Django email verification URL with token parameter

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create an email verification auth, but I'm unable to access this URL

```
127.0.0.1:8000/activate/d34324/KYJsqYMoV5DJ0vewSBdC9KZlZtnOAU7KE
```

How can I create proper routes for this code?

**urls.py**

```python
url(r'^logout/$', OwnerRegister.logout_view),
url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',OwnerRegister.activate,name='activate'),
```

**views.py**

```python
class OwnerRegister(TemplateView):
    template_name = "owner_register.html"

    def get_context_data(self, * args, ** kwargs):
        context = super(OwnerRegister, self).get_context_data()
        return context

    def logout_view(request):
        logout(request)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

    def activate(request, uidb64, token):
        try:
            print('\n\n request',request)

            user_id = request.GET.get('uid')
            token = request.GET.get('token')
            user = User.objects.get(username=user_id)
            profile = OwnerInfo.objects.get(user=user)
            print(user.date_joined)

            if profile.confirmation_code == token and user.date_joined > (datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=1)):
                print("test")
                user.is_active = True
                user.save()

                user.backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' 
                auth_login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('You have activated this account')
        except:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')


def send_registration_confirmation(self,user,request):
    p = OwnerInfo.objects.get(user=user)
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    content = current_site.domain+"/activate" +  user.username + "/" + str(p.confirmation_code) 
    send_mail("Email Verify", content, 'no-reply@gsick.com', [user.email], fail_silently=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notwithstanding any other problems you may have in your code, there appears to be a problem with your URL pattern declaration. Specifically, the URL pattern specifies the following regex for the `token` named parameter and the trailing slash:

```
(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/
```

The string passed in as `token` in the URL [does not match this regex](https://regex101.com/r/kDfIvr/2) as it is missing a hyphen after its thirteenth character.

Your URL also does not have a trailing slash. This is fine provided Django's `APPEND_SLASH` option is enabled ([the default behaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#append-slash)), which will cause Django to automatically issue a redirect to add a trailing slash when no URL pattern is found without one.

You should either change the mechanism used to generate the token in the URL to ensure it matches the regex (adding a hyphen [indeed does so](https://regex101.com/r/QbwZZF/2)), or vice-versa.

Comment: i tyred this http://127.0.0.1:8000/activate/KYJsqYMoV5DJ0vewSBdC9KZlZtnOAU7KE

    url(r'^activate/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',OwnerRegister.activate,name='activate')

but still returning 404

Comment: You still have a hyphen (`-`) in the regex between the `{1,13}` and the second character class, but no hyphen in the token in the URL.